# Can something "hold a property"

Tags: verbs, nouns, collocation

In academic writing, it is common to refer to or prove properties about the main object of an article.

If I prove a property for (some object), I know I can use the phrase:

> Property X **holds** for the object Y.

But, can an object hold a property?

> Furthermore, object Y **holds** some additional properties.

It always sounded "natural" to me (I'm not a native speaker), but now that I'm trying to verify my sentence construction using Google, I just can't seem to find anything useful.

Comment: An object *holding* a property can imply something different: "Looking at the specification the objects of the connections variable doesn't seem to hold a property/function to check if the connection is still alive." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662089/javascript-how-to-know-if-a-connection-with-a-shared-worker-is-still-alive

Comment: @Kris how is that example different? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: It is elaborate and more at the link. If that doesn't help, you need more background preparation in the subject of OOP, not the English language.

Comment: @Kris, I've been programming for years now. But the "property" in OOP comes from exactly that -- you're modeling an object, and methods (functions) belonging to that object will model the properties of that object (... "which that object holds")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Property X holds for the object Y.

This uses *hold* in the sense "to be valid or true". We can also use "holds true for".

> Furthermore, object Y holds some additional properties.

This is using *hold* in the sense "to have, to possess". So it's valid, but that the same word is used for each is a coincidence.

The latter is a rare use though. I would favour *has* or maybe *exhibits*, over *holds* as more usual.

Comment: I was aware of the fact that it's used with a different meaning, as you said "the sense you use it in is different". It was just somebodies comment when reading my writing: "I've seen this already in the form A (1st example), but not in this form B you're using (2nd example)" But, thank you for your answers, especially fore more common alternatives.

Comment: @John Hanna. The second form is not rare in academic writing.

Comment: @TheFrog all the better then. Would you say it was as common as *exhibits* or *has*, though?

Comment: @TheFrog That must be where I picked up the phrase in the first place :)